# Mat Cards not rearranging to same line after ngIf filter

Tags: angular-material, angular-ng-if, angular-flex-layout, ng-container

I'm trying to understand what part of my code is causing the mat-cards I have on my dashboard to not fill the same row after the toggle button is clicked to fulfill the *ngIf condition. I used the inspect tool on the browser and I think the issue is that it still thinks there's a card there when there really isn't. Firing off another API call to update the cards doesn't sound right so i'm guessing using the *ngIf was the right method but I can't seem to understand why it doesn't actually remove and display the cards I want on the same line. It might also have something to do with the Flex layout responsiveness? Using an ng-container seemed to resolve the issue of the cards being on different rows but it removed any of the Flex layout responsiveness that I need to keep the dashboard neat. I'm guessing there's something i'm just not doing right here, would appreciate some help!

This is the code for the container of the mat-card

```
<div style="padding-left: 60px; padding-top: 16px;" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="8px">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let pvsTrip of pvsTrips; let i = index" >
          <div *ngIf="(milesToggle && pvsMilesVariance.includes(pvsTrip.scheduleNum)) || !milesToggle" fxFlex.gt-md="32%" fxFlex.lt-sm="100%" fxFlex.md="48%"
            fxLayout.lt-sm="column">
              <div *ngIf = "(cToggle && !ncToggle && !neToggle && compliance.includes(pvsTrip.scheduleNum)) || (!cToggle && ncToggle && !neToggle && compliance.includes(pvsTrip.scheduleNum)) || (!cToggle && !ncToggle && neToggle && compliance.includes(pvsTrip.scheduleNum)) || (!cToggle && !ncToggle && !neToggle)">
                    <mat-card> 
                    </mat-card>
```

Apologies in advance for the messy screenshots. I have data on there that I can't expose.

[image: This is what shows up in the blanks spaces next to the cards]

[image: Before filtering]

[image: After filtering]

Comment: Try moving your *ngIf logic that is associated with the toggle to an `ng-container` right after the `ngFor` loop. That way there will be no element rendered if the toggle is off.

Comment: Thanks but I want to be able to see all of the cards when the toggle is off. The toggle buttons filter the cards based on the information on them. The issue is more about the extra space around the cards that is causing them to not line up on the same row